# How to print out a recursive decision tree?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I need to print out a recursion tree as seen below. I want this code to be general and work for other trees. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to print a recursion tree.

PrintDt ( Tennis ) using this dictionary, for example:

```
Tennis = ['skurple type', {'gloomp': 'Yes', 'murket': ['which murket', {'grabe': ['grabetime', {'sproon': 'No', 'midnort': 'Yes'}], 'carfer': 'Yes', 'glambit': 'No'}], 'snarzle': ['froovencity level', {'granky': 'No', 'slipely': 'Yes'}]}]
```

Where the output should be:

Split on skurple type

```
If skurple type == gloomp
    Return: Yes
If skurple type == murket
    Split on which murket
    If which murket == grabe
        Split on grabetime
        If grabetime == sproon
            Return: No
        If grabetime == midnort
            Return: Yes
    If which murket == carfer
        Return: Yes
    If which murket == glambit
        Return: No
If skurple type == snarzle
    Split on froovencity level
    If froovencity level == granky
        Return: No
    If froovencity level == slipely
        Return: Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will work:

```
def PrintDt(tree, depth=0):
    if type(tree) == str:
        print depth*'\t', 'Return:', tree
    else:
        print depth*'\t', 'Split on', tree[0]
        for value in tree[1].keys():
            print depth*'\t', 'If', tree[0], '==', value 
            PrintDt(tree[1][value], depth + 1)
```

Example:

```
>>> def PrintDt(tree, depth=0):
...     if type(tree) == str:
...         print depth*'\t', 'Return:', tree
...     else:
...         print depth*'\t', 'Split on', tree[0]
...         for value in tree[1].keys():
...             print depth*'\t', 'If', tree[0], '==', value 
...             PrintDt(tree[1][value], depth + 1)
... 
>>> Tennis = ['skurple type', {'gloomp': 'Yes', 'murket': ['which murket', {'grabe': ['grabetime', {'sproon': 'No', 'midnort': 'Yes'}], 'carfer': 'Yes', 'glambit': 'No'}], 'snarzle': ['froovencity level', {'granky': 'No', 'slipely': 'Yes'}]}]
>>> PrintDt(Tennis)
 Split on skurple type
 If skurple type == gloomp
    Return: Yes
 If skurple type == murket
    Split on which murket
    If which murket == grabe
        Split on grabetime
        If grabetime == sproon
            Return: No
        If grabetime == midnort
            Return: Yes
    If which murket == carfer
        Return: Yes
    If which murket == glambit
        Return: No
 If skurple type == snarzle
    Split on froovencity level
    If froovencity level == granky
        Return: No
    If froovencity level == slipely
        Return: Yes
```